# How to derive $\frac{d}{dx}\left(x+1\right)^{\sin\left(x\right)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I need help to find derivative of: $\frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^{\sin x}$

i tried to do something like this..

$$(x+1)^{\sin x}\cdot \ln\left(x+1\right)=\sin x(x+1)^{\sin\left(x\right)-1}\cdot \ln(x+1)-(x+1)^{\sin(x)}\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}\:=\sin x(x+1)^{\sin\left(x\right)-1} \ln(x+1)-\frac{(x+1)^{\sin x}}{x+1}$$

I tried another way:

$\left(x+1\right)^{sinx}\:=\:ln\left(x+1\right)^{sinx}\:=\:sin\left(x\right)ln\left(x+1\right)\:=\:cos\:\cdot \:ln\left(x+1\right)+sin\left(x\right)\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}\:=\:cos\left(x\right)ln\left(x+1\right)\:+\:\frac{sin\left(x\right)}{x+1}$

ok i got the solution! I put it there, maybe this will help someone!

i used this rule : $e^a=e^{a\cdot ln\cdot e}$

$\left(x+1\right)^{sinx}=\:e^{sinx\cdot ln\left(x+1\right)}=\:e^{sinx\cdot ln\left(x+1\right)}\cdot cosx\:\cdot \:ln\left(x+1\right)\:+\:sinx\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}\:=\:\left(x+1\right)\left(cosxln\left(x+1\right)\:+\:\frac{sinx}{x+1}\right)$

Comment: you have a typo: it should be $\sin x \log(x+1)$

Comment: can you explain please why sinxlog(x+1)?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you have logged before differentiating, which is correct. When you log $(x+1)^{\sin x}$, you get the expression I gave you

Comment: I changed many instances of $sinx$ to $\sin x$.  Standard usage.  And I find it irritating to say the least to have numerous instances of things like \left(x+1\right) where (x+1) is enough.  \left( and right) should be used when the sizes of parentheses need adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

$$f(x) = (x+1)^{\sin{x}},$$ so $\ln{f} = \sin{x} \, \ln{(x+1)}$. Now we have:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \ln {f} = \frac{1}{f} \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \sin{x} \, \ln{(x+1)} \right] . $$

You can now solve for $f'$ once you expand the LHS of the equation.

Cheers!

Comment: can you explain please how you know that ln = sinxln(x+1)?

Comment: Of course. It's already a consequence of @E.T.'s comment. One of the properties of logarithms states that $\log{\alpha^\beta} = \beta \log \alpha$.

Comment: You can find this and a lot of other properties here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities. Hope this helps! Cheers.

Comment: i think that i dont understand the basic of trigo derive.
i know this log rule but i dont understand why you use it here..? 
why i cant use this rule for example: $a^x=a^x\cdot lna$ ?

Comment: I didn't use any derivatives, but taking logarithm to both sides. Of course, you are allow to use the property $x = e^{\log{x}}$ which leads you to $(x+1)^{\sin{x}} = e^{\ln{(x+1)^{\sin{x}}}} = e^{\sin{x} \ln{(x+1)}}$, which is equivalent to what I did.

Comment: ok, i think i understand the use of property $x=\:e^{logx}$, but can you explain me how can i know when to use log like in this example?

Comment: I usually try to avoid this property by proceeding as I did, i.e., using logarithmic differentiation so the only property I need to remember is that I posted before, $\log{\alpha^\beta} = \beta \log{\alpha}$. You can find a better ilustration of what you are asking in @E.T.'s answer. Cheers!

Comment: i tried to solve with your explain but i cant post it in comment.. i just edit now my topic and i'll be glad if you can check if it is correct!

Comment: I'm afraid the alternative way you put in your comment is not the best one. Let me have a closer look to it tomorrow since it's a bit late here in Spain. Sorry!